# Python - waiting for asyncio task in non-async __init__ of certain class

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm making a python class with an `__init__` function and a another function, let's say `f`. The `__init__` function is not async, but the other function is. Now, I'm trying to execute the other function from the `__init__`.

Things I've looked into:

- I've found some code with get_event_loop/get_running_loop and run_until_complete, but this gives a RuntimeError that the event loop is already running.
- I've seen comments about nest_asyncio, but it seems a bit dirty.
- Further, I've tried several things using create_task, gather, and wait. But in this case, the code is not waiting until the task has been completely executed.
- I could split it up by first calling the constructor and then calling the second function with an await, but I'd like the second function to be called during the constructor.

Note that this is within an Azure Function App context.

Some sample code:

```
import asyncio
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        #asyncio.create_task(self.f('abc'))
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.f('abc'))
    
    async def f(self, x):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.x = x
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cl = myClass(1,2)
    print(cl.x)
```

This works fine within this simple context, but not within a more complex context as in Azure Functions, where I'm trying to use myClass in a function and then want to use its "x" property.

Comment: do you really need to call the async function from the `__init__`? you might want to run that after initialization or provide an async `classmethod` to run the async code then pass the result to the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code inside `__init__` cannot use `await` so you need to do 1 of 2 things.

either start some async tasks in `__init__` and provide a second method to wait on them:

```py
import asyncio
class myClass(object):
    """ must await on obj.finish_init() before the object can be used """
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self._finish_init_promise = asyncio.create_task(self.f('abc'))
        #self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        #self.loop.run_until_complete(self.f('abc'))
    async def finish_init(self):
        await self._finish_init_promise
        return self
    
    async def f(self, x):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.x = x
async def main():
    cl = await myClass(1,2).finish_init()
    print(cl.x)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

However it may be undesirable to have an incomplete object constructed (you may want to have a boolean to indicate whether it is ready or not) so an alternative is to provide an async `classmethod` to prepare the data and then pass that data to the constructor:

```py
import asyncio
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, x):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.x = x
    @classmethod
    async def make(cls, arg1, arg2):
        x = await cls.obvious_example_will_be_replaced_with_real_use_case('abc')
        return cls(arg1, arg2, x)
    @staticmethod
    async def obvious_example_will_be_replaced_with_real_use_case(x):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return x
async def main():
    cl = await myClass.make(1,2)
    print(cl.x)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Ok, seems like enter is not making newline in comment box, good to know. Anyway, both great suggestions! Question about second alternative though: does "make" have to be a class method and why? Also, in the "make" function, shouldn't it await cls.obvious...?

Comment: you are very correct there should have been `x = await ...` I have fixed.  `make` can't be a regular method since it has to be called before an instance is constructed, a global function would be weird because it is very tied to the class.  Using `staticmethod` and referring to the class by name works too, but a `classmethod` means that a subclass could use `make` to instantiate the subclass so that gives more expandability that you may not need.